# Laptop harddisk produces clicking sound

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

This happens when I am booting up into windows, shutdown or things in which I access the harddrive excessively. It doesn't happen all the time. I have checked it with "**Crystal disk Info**" and it displays no problem, and shows HDD to perfectly fine. Should I be worried about my HDD? I have Hitachi HDD in laptop.

- Some times my harddrive temps reach upto 43C while watching movies or playing games.
- What are the normal temps, which are safe for HDD to operate and increase the lifetime of HDD.

Thanks

Comment: But how do you distinguish between sounds coming from a hard disk with noise that’s made by the fans or something else?

Comment: Are you sure you don't just mean head-seeking clicks? Some drives are noisy and others nearly silent, and perhaps the sound can vary a little if your laptop is held at a different angle or sat on a different surface, but a click sound every time the head seeks is normal, and that can happen a lot during startup and shutdown etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform following steps to Check the Health of your Hard Drive:

- **Step 1: Check your hard disk for errors**
  Use [Chkdsk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491051.aspx) to detect and remove HDD errors.(you can also access it from Properties window)
- **Step 2: Understand the sounds of your disk**
  Here’s a useful [page](http://datacent.com/hard_drive_sounds.php) where you can listen to recorded sounds of various hard drives that have lead to a crash. If your disk is making a similar sound, get a replacement quickly.
- **Step 3: Thoroughly test your Hard Disk** (***Important***)
  [SeaTools](http://www.seagate.com/support/downloads/seatools/) is free diagnostic tool that can completely test your hard drive regardless of the OS installed on it. The tool is provided by Seagate but it works with non-Seagate   disk drives as well.

See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/94166/maximum-temperature-laptop-internals-can-handle-cooling-options) question for **Safe Temperature** for Laptop Internals.

Comment: thank God. None of the sound is like mine. I guess Steve314 is right. They are probably head seeks sounds.